# Ternary Conditional Operator for nil/not nil

Tags: ios, swift

I can use the ternary conditional operator for an `if {} else {}` statement like this: `a ? x : y`, or `question ? answer1 : answer2`.

Is it possible to use this format to check if, instead of whether `a` is `true` or `false`, `a == nil` or `a != nil`?

---

**UPDATE:** This was arguably the biggest brain fart of my career.

Comment: a == nil and a != nil result in a true or false, so yes. It would look like this: a == nil ? x : y

Comment: `a ?` is a short form for `a == true ?`, so you can check anything – which conforms to Equatable – for equation. Have you ever used Playgrounds? ;-)

Comment: I'm not a python developer, but assume there is a way of testing this kind of things using the terminal/command, in an interactive way. Or you can just use: https://www.python.org/shell/

Comment: @SalomãoRodrigues `I'm not a python developer` it's ok, since this is not a Python question... ;)

Comment: No, `a ?` is not a short form for `a == true ?`. I can define e.g. `func ==(lhs: String, rhs: Bool) -> Bool`, and Swift will then allow `"foo" == true`, but it still won't allow `"foo" ? 7 : 9`.

Comment: @robmayoff To clarify, I mean particularly `a` regarded as boolean, otherwise the statement `a ? x : y` won't compile

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this:

```
(a == nil) ? x : y
```

(Parentheses are not required but may make the code clearer.)

You can do this if you want something more confusing:

```
a.map { _ in x } ?? y
```

Answer (score 6):

```
  a != nil ? a! : b
```

> The code above uses the ternary conditional operator and forced unwrapping (a!) to access the value wrapped inside a when a is not nil, and to return b otherwise. The nil coalescing operator provides a more elegant way to encapsulate this conditional checking and unwrapping in a concise and readable form.

example :

```
let defaultColorName = "red"
var userDefinedColorName: String?   // defaults to nil

var colorNameToUse = userDefinedColorName ?? defaultColorName
// userDefinedColorName is nil, so colorNameToUse is set to the default of "red"
```

Reference : [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

Comment: @Hamish : yeah it was for checking that string is nil or not!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator as long as your statement returns boolean value. Here, a == nil or a != nil returns boolean value so 'Yes' you can use it.